# Cyclomatic complexity (Vg) - minimal or exact number of minimum of independent paths?

Tags: math, graph, cyclomatic-complexity

I thought that Vg=minimal number of independent paths but today I saw a presentation of one of my teachers and it said: Vg is equal or greater than number of independent paths. It is true?
I was sure that when counting cyclomatix complexity, it is always the minimal possible number of independent paths.

Comment: Have you asked your teacher what was meant?  Are there any diagrams to demonstrate this that can help understand your point (or the teacher's)?  Is it possible you just misheard what was said (or the teacher accidentally misspoke)?

Answer (score 0):

details explained here

Structured Testing: A Testing Methodology Using the Cyclomatic Complexity Metric

http://hissa.nist.gov/HHRFdata/Artifacts/ITLdoc/235/title.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.